# Zend Framework 2: Debugging Plugin

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework2

Relying on PHP's error reporting and backtracing is quite a pain and messages are hard to read at times. Before, I had no choice but to bear with it. Not until I found this http://zfskeleton.onlime.ch/index/foo which I think is really awesome. Sadly, it is not made for ZF2.

Can you suggest a similar ZF2 plugin I can use to make error reporting and backtracing less painful?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Erm just to say this out loud, but going by the link you've provided, the plugin does NOTHING more but to STYLE the debugging output. There's not a single additional information. Either the `Exceptions` are helpful to you or you should start to use real debugging Tools like xdebug.

Comment: @Sam: Yeah, it is. The point is... anyway. Nevermind. Remi got my drift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found only these using http://packagist.org/ and http://modules.zendframework.com/ :

- https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools
- https://github.com/webino/ZF2NetteDebug
- https://github.com/ghislainf/zf2-whoops

You can try to load your ZF1 debug library :

http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/zend-framework-2-using-zend-framework-1-libraries-in-zend-framework-2/

Comment: Thanks a heap, @Remi. Upped and Accepted! ;)